# Code wont return sum when trying to get all numbers between 1 to n added together

Tags: java

I am trying to get the code to to add all numbers from 1 to n, however when i try and return the sum, i keep getting an error saying it cant be resolved to a variable.

```
public class methodCalls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
    public static int sum(int n) {
        //int sum;
        for (int i=1; i<=n;i++) {
            int sum = 0;
             sum +=1;

        }
        return sum;

    }

}
```

Comment: `sum` is declared inside the for loop, so it is not visible outside the for loop, where your return statement is.

Comment: `return ((n+1)*n)/2;`

Comment: int sum = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<=n;i++) {
         
             sum +=1;

        }
        return sum;

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58927058/10785239) question posted to get Badge :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class methodCalls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
    public static int sum(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<=n;i++) {
            //int sum = 0;
             sum +=1;

        }
        return sum;

    }

}
```

The `sum` variable needs to be outside of loop, because for each loop, the variable will be reinitialized.  Secondly, the error you mention is because you needs to declare default value of method level variable.

EDIT: I like @Elliot's solution in comments above better.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying the return the sum variable which is out of scope there.
Other that that to get the `sum` from `1` to `n` you need to do this `sum = sum + i`

```
public static int sum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         sum = sum+i;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `sum` is declared inside the for loop and its scope is within the loop. The variable won't be accessible outside of the loop and that's why you are getting the error that you mentioned.

Please try this :

```
public static int sum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```